# iphone/ipad chrome apache keepalive off issue

Tags: ios, iphone, apache, ipad, google-chrome

I have an Apache web-server, when I try to reach the website from any device and browser it works fine until I try to use ipad/iphone and chrome on it (chrome on other platforms works fine). The issue is this: when I open a new tab and try to reach my site it keeps loading forever, once I click "stop" and then "refresh" it loads quickly and all is well. I have done many tests, if I just use a simple "hello world" site then it works, if I add one image the site works fine once I add a second image I get the issue (same for other included files such as CSS files).
I need to have my KeepAlive set to Off for other functionality issues, I have tried changing this to On and it seems to help a bit so that some of the web site is loaded but not all and so the issue persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if anyone has encountered this but after a lot of testing and research (and I mean a lot!) we have come to the conclusion that this is a bug with chrome for iOS. We have notified google.
IMPORTANT: this issue only appears when using a self-signed certificate (or any untrusted ones).